# Как получить доступ к DataGridView из другого класса

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть форма `Form1` на которой, через дизайнер, я создаю компонент `DataGridView`. И есть класс `openAndReadCSV`, в котором я хочу открыть, прочитать и записать csv-файл в `List`. После этого данные из листа записать в `DataGridView`.

Код `openAndReadCSV`

```
public class openAndReadCSV : Form1
{
    public static void reading() {

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv) | *.csv";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                var i = 0;
                var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(openFileDialog1.FileName));
                List<string> listA = new List<string>();
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(';');
                    listA.Add(values[0]);                 
                    i++;
                }
                MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }

    }


}
```

Как мне скопировать данные из `List` в `DataGridView`?

Comment: Судя по всему WinForms?  openAndReadCSV - наследуется от Form1 - так задумано или случайность? Если так задумано, и нужен доступ к элементам родительского класса - просто сделайте нужные элементы protected вместо private.

Comment: поставил protected. не работает

Comment: "поставил protected. не работает" здорово, а что именно не работает? Я не вижу в приведенном вами коде обращений к DataGridView, вижу только чтение файла.

Comment: Form1 frm = new Form1(); frm.dataGrid.Rows.Add(values[0]);

Comment: Эм... а зачем так? openAndReadCSV наследуется от Form1, а значит тоже форма со всеми элементами Form1. Достаточно написать this.dataGrid.Rows.Add(values[0]); (this - можно не писать)

Comment: или все таки наследование тут случайное?

Comment: @rdorn, так тоже не работает. `An object reference is required for the non-static 
`.

Comment: Ошибка компиляции? или исключение в runtime? И что пишет? dataGrid.DataSource = ListA; пробовали?

Comment: ошибка была изза наследования. убрал наследование. теперь когда вызываю метод ничего не происходит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43400/discussion-between-rdorn-and-vadim).

Comment: вам чат уже доступен?

Comment: я кажется понял что вы хотите сделать, вечером напишу как это сделать правильно, если ответа все еще не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то, в первом приближении, вам требуется отобразить содержимое `CSV` на `DataGridView`. Эту задачу можно разбить на два этапа:

1. Прочитать файл и распарсить его в удобный для дальнейшей работы объект(ы).
2. Отобразить полученный результат на `DataGridView`.

В простейшем случае для этого не требуется отдельный класс, достаточно вынести обработку исходного файла в отдельный метод. Причем этот метод не должен ни чего знать ни о том, как будут отображаться результат его работы, ни о том, откуда взялся файл. Кроме этого нам потребуется класс для представления одной строки `CSV`. Можно обойтись и без него, но позже увидите зачем это нужно. Т.к. я не знаю (а вы не указали в вопросе) структуру исходного `CSV`, будем считать что в нем гарантировано есть два столбца. Тогда класс для представления строки может выглядеть так:

```
public class CsvRow
{
    public string FirstField { get; set; }
    public string SecondField { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь выделим из вашего фрагмента чтение и парсинг в отдельный метод, который будет возвращать `List<CsvRow>` в качестве результата обработки:

```
private List<CsvRow>ParseCsv(string fileName)
{
    var result = new List<CsvRow>();
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
    {
        var values = line.Split(';');
        var row = new CsvRow()
        {
            FirstField = values[0],
            SecondField = values[1]
        }
        result.Add(row); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

И помещаем полученный метод в код формы или отдельный класс с хелперами. С парсером закончили - отображем результат. Пусть у нас есть кнопка, при клике по которой, пользователь выбирает файл для отображения.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ParseCsv(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

На этом собственно все.

Но я обещал рассказать зачем нужен класс для данных. Дело в том, что `DataGridView` не умеет работать с полями - только со свойствами. Для каждого публичного свойства будет создана отдельная колонка и одна строка грида будет содержать значения свойств в соответствующих ячейках. В противном случае, заполнять грид придется руками.

**Альтернативные варианты**

1. Реализовать в `Form1` интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, создать публичное поле типа `List<T>` инициирующее событие `PropertyChanged` при записи в него значений и, в обработчике события, подгружать лист в `DataSource` грида. Немного сложнее, но в ряде случаев очень даже удобен.
2. **Не рекомендуется** задать самому гриду уровень доступа `public` и работать с ним напрямую. Этот вариант нарушает инкапсуляцию, привожу его только потому что он тоже возможен, но категорически не рекомендуется к практическому применению никогда.

**PS:** В приведенном коде намерено опущены проверки при работе с файлом и некоторые другие, чтобы не загромождать код и донести основную идею.